# Naming Segments and Angles in Geometry

Tags: geometry, notation

I am curious to see how people name their Angles and Line Segments in solving geometry problems because sometimes I get confused between line segment $AB$ and line segment $BA$. It gets especially tricky in more complicated geometry problems where certain equations that were derived look different because line segments are named differently.

Comment: When I see a segment AB, I call it AB, and when I see a segment BA, I call it BA. Now what was your question again?

Comment: It's a matter of taste whether $AB$ is a different line segment from $BA$, and whether $\angle ABC$ is a different angle from $\angle CBA$. I'm personally leaning more on the side of them being the same (which means I usually prefer alphabetical order).

Comment: Line segments are usually unoriented (otherwise one might prefer a vector). $AB$ and $BA$ are synonymous.

Comment: I get sort of confused when there are multiple segments/angles in an equation and they are not in the same order. Was just curious if people have a convention for naming segments because sometimes AB=BA gets me confused (Angles are more different since there are directed angles and such).

Comment: Maybe directed angles come up more often, but directed line segments are definitely a thing.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to engage with your problem abstractly. If you could give us an example where something confuses you, it might be easier for us to help you.

Comment: In the problems where AB and BA are equivalent, I use them interchangeably, and when they are not, I use them differently. It is as simple as that.

Comment: So, can you give us an example, Super?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: @SuperMage1: If you are familiar/comfortable with directed angles, then you can become so with directed segments. In the absence of the notion of directed angles, we take "$\angle ABC$" and "$\angle CBA$" to mean *the same thing* (which is why we often unambiguously shorten the name to "$\angle B$"). So it is with segments; if direction is irrelevant, then "$\overline{AB}$" and "$\overline{BA}$" mean *the same thing*. In contexts (eg, [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem)) where "directed segments" are helpful, we distinguish them by the order of letters in the name.

Answer (score 0):

well there are some rules for naming lines and dots and other shapes. dots should be names by capital letters and for naming shapes if you start from a certain vertex you have to keep going from that in one direction( clockwise or anti clockwise). and about what you said about confusing well there is no difference if you say AB or BA